# Setup a server at 192.168.1.x which is accessible by 10.1.1.x

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ftp, webserver

My University provides each hotel room with a LAN connection (with IP of form 10.1.1.x) which is in the same network as the rest of the campus network. Since I need multiple devices to connect to the internet, I have connected the LAN to a router and all of my devices are connected to the router and are assigned IP address in 192.168.1.X format.

Now I have set up an FTP server at my laptop (IP say 192.168.1.10) but I want to access the server from a lab PC (with IP say 10.1.1.10). I'm not sure how to go about this. I know that just typing out ftp://192.168.1.10 won't work (but it will work with another laptop connected to my router) I must point out that the reverse works well (server on 10.1.1.10 accessed via 192.168.1.10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will need to do is port forward on your router so that computers on the university network can connect to your FTP server.

However, this can be a little complicated with an FTP server. FTP servers have a control connection and a data connection. The control connection is almost always on port 21. But the data connection is established dynamically after the control connection is established. Additionally, depending on if you are running in passive mode or active mode will determine if additional ports need to be forwarded.

In active mode, your server makes the data connection back out to the client. This mode is almost never used because it is insecure for your server and rarely works because the client is usually behind NAT.

In passive mode, the client makes both the control connection and the data connection. The server tells the client to connect to one of a range of random ports to establish the data connection.

Therefore, port forwarding is needed for both the control port and data ports. The control port, as mentioned, is port 21. The data port is usually a range of ports configured on your FTP server. That entire range has to be forwarded on your router.

So, ultimately it might look like this:

1. Port 21 forwards to 192.168.1.10
2. Ports 30000-31000 forwards to 192.168.1.10 (assuming your FTP server is configured to use those ports for data)

Next, computers from the 10.x.x.x university network will connect to the WAN IP of your router. Your router will have a 10.x.x.x address that it receives from the university network. That is the IP you will use to connect to your FTP server after you forward the proper ports on your router.

It’s worth noting that your WAN IP will likely change periodically because the address is probably dynamic, so you will need to be on the lookout for that.

Finally, it is also important to use a static IP on your FTP server so that it’s address does not change as well, which will break the port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

In order to go from one subnet to another, you need to go via a gateway.  That could be your default gateway, or some other gateway to a specific subnet or range of subnets.

What you want can be done with basic port forwarding on your router.  Can be done via the web interface of your router - just use the right ports, see https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/ftp/ftp-port-connection/

You will need to forward ports on your router from the WAN interface to the IP of the FTP server, and others on the WAN side of the network will need simply connect to your WAN IP (192.168.1.10).  The router will forward the appropriate ports from that IP to your internal 10.1.1.10 address.